# Is this possible to access Google Places Dashboard using API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am developing an application where I need to retrieve Google Place Dashboard Insight data using Google Places API or Google Analytic. I am looking for documentation and sample code for this for the last 6 hours with no luck! :(

Does anybody know if there is a way to to do this? It looks to me there is nothing like this yet, but I would be extremely happy to see I am wrong, and there is a way to do this!

[image]

I am looking for the same for the last 6 hours but does not seem like there is any. Even that has gone worse when I saw this post here: http://places.blumenthals.com/threade8ae.html. However, the thread was closed way back in 2011, so I hope Google has developed something for this!

Maximum accessibility to Google Places API is limited to Search, Business Detail etc. but I need to access the insight metrics like Impressions, Actions, Clicks more info, Clicks for direction, Clicks to website.

Is there any HTTP Get request to handle a REST API and throw me the data from Google server? If yes, please provide me the link to documentation. My application is platformed in ASP.NET 4.0, so a .net client would be handy as well.